# ADT installation failure

Tags: android

I tried to install ADT plugin on my fedora 15 system . But I couldn't do it.When I used  http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/   instead of    https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/, it failed though  and got error log as
Communication with repository at http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ failed.

Please help me to fix this

Answer (score 0):

Try `http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/` WITHOUT the "s". Sometimes using https causes issues.